# Remove elevation shadow without removing elevation itself

Tags: android, android-toolbar, shadow, android-appbarlayout, android-elevation

Is there a way for `AppBarLayout` to no drop shadow and keep its elevation?

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        app:elevation="0dp">
```

Comment: Why do you want to keep the elevation without shadow?

Comment: @azizbekian Because I have a nested scroll content that I need to scroll behind bar and a semi transparent image view header

Comment: If you make all of those view's have the same elevation value, then they'll end up being on the one z ordering, thus no shadow would be shown.

Comment: @azizbekian indeed but unfortunately  my nested scroll content goes over the `ImageView` in the `AppBarLayout` in that case

Comment: Restructure your layout in a way, that `AppBarLayout` is declared at the end of the `xml` file, thus it will be always drawn on top of `NestedScrollView`.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

To complete M.Sandholtz answer, you can also define this in XML, with outlineProvider="none".

```xml
<View
    android:id="@+id/viewElevationNoShadow"
    android:outlineProvider="none"
    android:elevation="4dp" />
```

Comment: Only for API >= v21

Answer (score 39):

I just ran into this same problem and this is what fixed it for me:

```
val withElevationNoShadow = view.findViewById<*your view type*>(*your view id*)
withElevationNoShadow.outlineProvider = null
```

Keep in mind that the code above is Kotlin, but the Java is almost identical.

This works because shadows are drawn by `ViewOutlineProvider`s. By setting your view's `ViewOutlineProvider` to `null`, you take away the default shadow.

For more info about `ViewOutlineProvider`s check out

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewOutlineProvider

and

https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping

Comment: Works lika a charm, this should be the accepted answer.